# Error:Using GridView with Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, gridview

I have a fragment MobilesFragment and I want to show a gridview inside it, which will contain two textviews and an imageview, but on my first run, th is an exception which is occuring,

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x64
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2863)
        at com.devs.fookart.GridViewAdapter.getView(GridViewAdapter.java:54)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
        at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:935)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
        at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My gridview layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dataGrid"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >
</GridView>
```

Here is my Fragment class:

```
package com.ui.fragments;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

import com.data.dataclass.GridViewData;
import com.devs.fookart.GridViewAdapter;
import com.devs.fookart.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MobilesFragment extends Fragment
{   private GridViewAdapter adapter;
private GridView mList;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<GridViewData> gridItems;
private String titles[]={"Headphones","Camera","Home","Mobile"};
private int prices[]={100,122,212,122};
private ArrayList<Bitmap> bmp;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mobiles,container,false);
    context=container.getContext();
    bmp=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    bmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_headphones));
    bmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_camera));
    bmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_home));
    bmp.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_mobile));
    gridItems=new ArrayList<GridViewData>();
    mList=(GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dataGrid);
    gridItems.add(new GridViewData(1,titles[0],bmp.get(2),prices[0]));
    gridItems.add(new GridViewData(2,titles[1],bmp.get(2),prices[1]));
    gridItems.add(new GridViewData(3,titles[2],bmp.get(3),prices[2]));
    gridItems.add(new GridViewData(4,titles[3],bmp.get(2),prices[3]));

    adapter=new GridViewAdapter(context,gridItems);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

GridItem Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Title"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_weight="0.02" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/product"
    android:layout_weight="0.36"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Price"
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_weight="0.02" />
</LinearLayout>
```

GridViewData class:

```
package com.data.dataclass;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class GridViewData
{   private String name;
private int price,id;
private Bitmap image;

public GridViewData(int id,String name,Bitmap image,int price)
{   this.name=name;
    this.image=image;
    this.price=price;
    this.id=id;
}

public int getId()
{   return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{   this.id = id;
}

public String getName()
{   return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{   this.name=name;
}

public int getPrice()
{   return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price)
{   this.price=price;
}

public Bitmap getImage()
{   return image;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image)
{   this.image=image;
}
}
```

At last GridView Adapter class:

```
package com.devs.fookart;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import com.data.dataclass.GridViewData;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{   private ArrayList<GridViewData> GridItem;
private Context context;

public GridViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<GridViewData> GridItem)
{   this.context=context;
    this.GridItem=GridItem;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{   return GridItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{   return GridItem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{   return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{   if(convertView==null)
    {   LayoutInflater mInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_grid,null);;
    }
    ImageView img=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.product);
    TextView title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView price=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    img.setImageBitmap(GridItem.get(position).getImage());
    title.setText(GridItem.get(position).getName());
    price.setText(GridItem.get(position).getPrice());
    return convertView;
}
}
```

It will be a huge help, Thanks a ton in advance....

Comment: Possible Duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285634/how-to-gridview-inside-a-fragment

Comment: @AdityaRamkumar: The duplicate you have marked has nothing to do with this issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `getPrice()` is returning an `int` and you are passing it to setText(), which can cause this problem, because this integer is interpreted as a resource identifier for some string in `strings.xml` like `R.string.hello_world`.

Change this:

```
price.setText(GridItem.get(position).getPrice());
```

to this:

```
price.setText(GridItem.get(position).getPrice()+"");
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: @AngadSingh Sorry, I made a change. Try now

Comment: Sorry dont have enough reputation, i will upvote it asap...:)

Comment: You cannot upvote the answer, but you can still accept it (Green check mark on the left of this answer). Please do it. :)

Comment: There you go...Done..:)